# Reset Array in a function throw an exception AngularJS

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, json, angularjs

I have a variable under my scope and when I try to reset it in a function it is throwing me an exception.

Controller variable declaration:

```
angular.module('timeSheetApp', []).controller('TimeSheetController', function ($scope, $http) {
$scope.TimeSheet = {
        Tables: [{
            Projects:{
                Project: ":)",
                Activities: [{
                    Activity:"",
                    Sun: 0.00,
                    Mon: 0.00,
                    Tue: 0.00,
                    Wen: 0.00,
                    Thu: 0.00,
                    Fri: 0.00,
                    Sat: 0.00,
                    Total: 0.00
                }],
                DefaultProjectText: "Select a Project",
                IsDisabled: true,
                ProjectNumber: 0,
                Day: {}
            }
        }],
};
```

});

When I call this function inside my controller sends an exception:

```
$scope.SetDays = function () {

    $scope.TimeSheet.Tables = [{
            Projects: {
                Project: ":)",
                Activities: [{
                    Activity: "",
                    Sun: 0.00,
                    Mon: 0.00,
                    Tue: 0.00,
                    Wen: 0.00,
                    Thu: 0.00,
                    Fri: 0.00,
                    Sat: 0.00,
                    Total: 0.00
                }],
                DefaultProjectText: "Select a Project",
                IsDisabled: true,
                ProjectNumber: 0,
                Day: {}
            }
        }]
}
```

Comment: might be while doing `$scope.TimeSheet.Tables` you don't have initialize `$scope.TimeSheet`

Comment: Can you add what the exception is? also if you can create a sample Fiddle, it would be really easy to understand/debug.

Comment: I just checked and when I call the function $scope.TimeSheet.Tables is initialized. This is the error: 0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%7B

Comment: Can you reproduce the error in a Plunker or JSFiddle?

Comment: use the full development version of angular to get more verbose error reporting

Comment: How can I use it? where is the full version library that I need?

Comment: Where can I find the full version?

Comment: The issue is reproducible here: https://jsfiddle.net/1u3netsj/ If you delete line number 132 the app works fine